# How do I enable the "stop and rerun" pop-up in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I accidentally disabled the "Stop and Rerun" pop-up asking me if I'm sure I want to rerun a debugging process:

[image]

As I actually find this pop-up useful, I want to re-enable it. Does anybody know how?